# How much do you know about higher-clearance colours?

Tags: paranoia

Is there any documentation or guidance (I am a player, not a GM), I can access to describe what colour levels you know about at each level? I.e., I know a red citizen wouldn't have knowledge of what Ultraviolet is, but I would probably know what Yellow was. Is there a cut off point, such as you would recognise Green but not blue?

Additionally is there a rule of thumb, such as "you recognise 3 levels above you", or "indigo citizens know enough to know their betters?"

I also know that asking about the game is treason. Please fill out a Treason Identification form and supply it to my GM.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The clearances and their colors are for your protection, citizen.  Everyone knows about them.

> Every citizen of Alpha Complex has a security clearance, indicating their
>   seniority within Alpha Complex and how much the Computer trusts them.
>   There are nine levels: Infrared is the lowest, then Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet and Ultraviolet.  (Guide to Alpha Complex, page 7.)

For complete newbie players to Paranoia, it can be fun to not let them in on what the colors mean, but they'll figure it out quickly. This trick only works once.

There are rumors about other clearances above Ultraviolet. Rumors are treason.

> At least one classic adventure introduces a GAMMA clearance above Ultraviolet. Another adventure has the Troubleshooters infiltrate another Alpha Complex and discover that there the colors are in reverse priority.

Comment: This of course begs the existence of an adventure in DTN sector where the Reds have been rendered chemically blind to colors Green and above for Important Computer Reasons.

Comment: Can you include the sources for the "other adventures" containing GAMMA clearance or another Alpha Complex?

Comment: @Glazius There's a campaign on YouTube where one player chose color-blindness as his tic.

Comment: Of course the riles of Alpha COmplex are yours, I went through a period of running Paranoia games where I would auto generate the hierarchy of the colours each campaign, it is amusing seeing the look of confusion on your trouble shooters faces when you tell them they are all dressed in blue and then have an infrared citizen giving them orders. It also leads to a period of fun as players try and work out where they sit in the pecking order this adventure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are any limits on knowing about the ranks, only information about things of those ranks. Even an Infrared would know about Ultraviolets, but would not know anything about there lives, duties or names.

Comment: This answer would be improved with support for the point that you are making regarding limits, or lack thereof, in knowing ranks.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - Oh, you'd like *that* wouldn't you?

Comment: @RDFozz Oh dear, am I wearing the wrong color?

Comment: Citizen, not providing support for your assertions is treason. Report for termination.